# UIView alpha = 0 causes touches to be dropped to the view below

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

So I created a glass pane or a custom UIView to handle touches. This glass pane sits on top of other views such as dummy UIButtons. When I set the alpha to be 0, the touches actually get intercepted by the views underneath the glass view. This is wrong. However, when I set the alpha to a low value like 0.2, the glass pane intercepts the touches.

The alpha setting was done in Interface Builder.

Anybody know how to set to the alpha to 0 and still get have this glass pane intercept touches?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it is standard behaviour.

For example, you can just set clear background of that `UIView`:

```
UIView *touchHandlerView;
touchHandlerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

In such case user wouldn't see that view - I assume that you want to do exactly that?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, `alpha=0.0f;` and `hidden=YES;` have the same effect.  This is very useful, because you can animate a fade-out and not have to worry about touches on the invisible object - ie you can say:

```
-(void)hideOverlayButton
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"hideOverlayButton" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [self.overlayButton setAlpha:0.0];
    [UIVIew commitAnimations];
}
```

Then, when the animation is complete, the button won't respond to touches - there's no need to worry about deactivating it.

If what you want is to have invisible buttons, put a UIButton on the view, make sure it's at the front (bottom of the list in interface builder), set it's type to custom; don't set an image, background image or title. By default in interface builder you'll get alpha of 1 and a clear color.Then you can wire-up the IBOutlets in the usual way.

Comment: The note about invisible buttons was useful. I didn't know that it should be custom button WITHOUT any image. Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know if UIView's with an alpha of 0 or hidden=YES are still 'drawn'? Are they still an expense to the CPU?

Comment: hi, Will,  "Using an alpha value requires that the graphics hardware blend each pixel from the object with everything underneath. It's compute-intensive. The hidden flag, on the other hand, is a switch. If you turn it on, the OS knows it doesn't have to draw the object at all." i got this from iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/65525-whats-the-difference-between-alpha0-and-hiddenyes.html , hope it can answer your question.