# UIView added as an UIWindow subview doesn't respond to taps

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I've added a `UIView` containing a `UITapGestureRecognizer` as my key window's subview. It shows properly, however when I tap my view, the target method is not fired. I've even tried to replace the gesture recognizer with a `UIButton`, still to no avail.

Here is my code.

**NotificationView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef NS_ENUM(int, NotificationKind) {
    NotificationKindActivity,
    NotificationKindReply,
};

@interface NotificationView : UIView {

    NotificationKind currentNotificationKind;

}

-(id)initWithMessage:(NSString*)message andColor:(UIColor*)color andKind:(NotificationKind)kind;
-(void)show;

@end
```

**NotificationView.m**

```
#import "NotificationView.h"

@implementation NotificationView

- (id)initWithMessage:(NSString*)message andColor:(UIColor*)color andKind:(NotificationKind)kind
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds), 60)];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setAlpha:0];
        [self setBackgroundColor:color];
        [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];


        currentNotificationKind = kind;

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        [label setNumberOfLines:0];
        [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Italic" size:20]];
        [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [label setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth:290];
        [label setText:message];
        [label setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [self addSubview:label];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(notificationTapped)];
        [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];

        [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:self];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)show{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

        [self setAlpha:1];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
            [self setAlpha:0];

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self removeFromSuperview];
        }];

    }];
}

-(void)notificationTapped{

    DDLogDebug(@"Notification tapped!");

}

@end
```

Comment: Total guess here, but you shouldn't re-assign "self".  Call super and don't use its return value.

Comment: Can you describe how this notification view is presented/dismissed? I ask because I am confused why you are first setting the alpha to zero which will disable any touches (mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/q/8091013/3055415) and in your method 'show' you bring the alpha to 1 then back to 0 then remove the view from the superview.

Comment: @MattS, I believe that this is default procedure when subclassing, it works properly everywhere else...

Comment: @JustinMoser, I create the view when I receive a remote notification. I just call the constructor which sets it up (GUI) and adds it to the key window. As you see, the alpha is 0 at that time. Now when I call `show` on the view, an animation changes the views alpha to 1 in 0.3s, waits 3s, sets its alpha back to 0 in 0.3s and removes the view from the `superview`. It does exactly what it is supposed to (the animation even looks good), however I can't tap it.

Comment: @MartinHerman Ah, I see!  If everything else is correct then all you should need is one small addition.  Add UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction to your 3-second animation block like so: `[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations^{...`

Comment: DBD beat me to it.  I hadn't re-read his updated answer :)

Comment: @JustinMoser, both of you were right indeed, check out below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When this happens to me it's usually because I screwed up my `UIView` frame. I see all the content as expected because my `UIView` isn't clipping to bounds, but I can't interact with anything because my taps are outside the bounds of the `UIView`.

My simple test is to change the background color of the `UIView` and see if it covers the area I expect or if I screwed up size/placement somehow.

I used to pound my head against the wall with this issue, struggling for hours, but I've done it so many times now it's 5min fix of "Oh that again".

**Edit:**

Then I'd look at your `show` code. Your calling code isn't here, but if I'm to assume your are just using your `show` code and your view is only on screen for 3 seconds, then that's you problem.

As Justin mentioned (comment above) and Apple's docs

> During an animation, user interactions are temporarily disabled for
>   all views involved in the animation, regardless of the value in this
>   property. You can disable this behavior by specifying the
>   UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction option when configuring the
>   animation.

Since the entire time your view is on the screen it's part of an animation block, all interaction will be disable for the entire time it's visible. I've never quite tested the `delay` bit and whether animation was disabled during that piece, but it would not surprise me animation is disabled during the delay. The second animation is still inside the primary animation block, so I'd assume animations will be blocked until both are complete.

Comment: I can see the view itself... I'm setting a background colour. I'm 99.9% confident that the view's frame is okay.

Comment: Added another possibility to the answer.

Comment: you are absolutely right - once I set the `delay` to 0 and added the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` option, it worked fine. I now use GCD to add the delay. For anyone interested, I've added the corrected `.m` file as an answer.

Comment: Use `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` still can not respond the tap event, just becomes event-passable, why?

Answer (score 0):

Updated `NotificationView.m` file, as suggested by @DBD...

```
#import "NotificationView.h"

@implementation NotificationView

- (id)initWithMessage:(NSString*)message andColor:(UIColor*)color andKind:(NotificationKind)kind
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds), 60)];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setAlpha:0];
        [self setBackgroundColor:color];
        [self setClipsToBounds:YES];

        currentNotificationKind = kind;

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        [label setNumberOfLines:0];
        [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Italic" size:20]];
        [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [label setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth:290];
        [label setText:message];
        [self addSubview:label];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(notificationTapped)];
        [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];

        [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:self];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)show{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{

        [self setAlpha:1];

    } completion:nil];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 3 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
            [self setAlpha:0];

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self removeFromSuperview];
        }];

    });


}

-(void)notificationTapped{

    DDLogDebug(@"Notification tapped!");

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up being able to create a full-screen subview which accepted gestures by adding it to the app's keyWindow, assuming makeKeyAndVisible has been called first:

```
myView.hidden = YES;
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:myView];
```

Then to show it above the status bar:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1;
myView.hidden = NO;
```

And to change it back:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal;
myView.hidden = YES;
```

This just changes the position of your app's main window (including all of its subviews) within the window hierarchy. Hope that helps!

Comment: If you find solution for this please let me know

Comment: @Dutt Just edited my answer with the solution I found. I should have done it at the time!