# (Update) UITapGestureRecognizer Action is not called when using UIApplication

Tags: ios

I thought that I have solved the following error with inheriting from NSObject. The frustrating thing is that id did work once :-)

The beneth code should run(not wok) in any ViewController.

The problem is that the action(tapped) is not called: Can you see why not?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public class TestErrorClass: NSObject {

    var errorView: UIView?

    public override init() {}

    public func showErrorMessage(errorMessage: String) {

        let APPDELEGATE = UIApplication.shared.delegate as UIApplicationDelegate?

            if let window = APPDELEGATE?.window{
                let v = window?.subviews[0]

                self.errorView = UIView(frame: (v?.frame)!)
                self.errorView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

                let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped(_:)))
                tapGesture.isEnabled = true
                errorView!.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

                v?.addSubview(self.errorView!)
            }
        }

    @objc func tapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        errorView!.removeFromSuperview()
    }


}
```

Used in this code:

```
import UIKit

class NetKitSampleAppViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        let b = TestErrorClass()
        b.showErrorMessage(errorMessage: "Bla bal")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you call `showErrorMessage(_:)`?

Comment: Just from another func?

Comment: Is label visible?

Comment: Current code is working fine for me, seems issue with approach you calling `showErrorMessage(_:)` func.

Comment: Yes, it shows and it seems to be in the foreground - in XCode UI debugger / View Hierarchy

Comment: And do you add this on Main thread or with any animation?

Comment: Ok, thanks for verifying that it actually works.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25365338/3411787) may help.