# Why doesn't UITapGestureRecognizer work in subview of keyWindow (full screen)?

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I asked here ([UIView added as an UIWindow subview doesn't respond to taps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365228/uiview-added-as-an-uiwindow-subview-doesnt-respond-to-taps)) but I thought it deserved its own question.

If I set up a subclassed UIView (CustomView) this way, I can't get gestures to work within the view:

```
CustomView *customView = [[[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.frame];

customView.frame = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.bounds; // leaves space at bottom of screen if not here

[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:customView];
```

But if I set up this way, gestures work fine:

```
CustomView *customView = [[[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.frame];

customView.frame = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.bounds; // leaves space at bottom of screen if not here

[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows[0] addSubview:customView];
```

Note that using .windows[0] instead of .keyWindow means the status bar is still there, so I have to hide that when I unhide customView to get an empty full screen.

Within customView:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    id mainView;
    if (self)
    {
        NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomNib" owner:self options:nil];
        mainView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return mainView;
}
```

And here's the gesture setup, also within customView:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[self addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
```

Any ideas why the gesture recognizer doesn't work when the view is a subview of .keyWindow but works when the view is a subview of .windows[0]?

Answer (score 0):

In `initWithFrame`, you are returning a `UIView` --- *not* an instance of `CustomView`.

You probably want your `CustomView` code to look like this:

```
#import "CustomView.h"

@implementation CustomView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    UIView *mainView;
    if (self)
    {
        NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomNib" owner:self options:nil];
        mainView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
        mainView.frame = self.bounds;
        mainView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self addSubview:mainView];
        [self setupTap];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setupTap {

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];

}

- (void)handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)g {
    NSLog(@"Tap in CustomView!");
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, @DonMag. Unfortunately, this did not fix the problem.

Comment: I should mention that the subview added to [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow does not have any subviews inside of it, but it immediately starts playing a CAKeyframeAnimation via [self.layer addAnimation:self.animation forKey:@"backgroundColor"]; If the subview is added to [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows[0], it gesture works fine.

Comment: Maybe you *need* a subview then? If you post your full `CustomView` I will take a look.