# UISlider Does Not Get Selected If Alpha is set 0 in viewDidLoad and Then Fades In

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I programatically added a UISlider in my view. Also, added the function for `sliderValueDidChange` to observe the change on slider.

```
var durationSlider: UISlider!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    durationSlider = UISlider(frame:CGRectMake(0, 600, self.view.bounds.width, 20))
    durationSlider.minimumValue = 0
    durationSlider.maximumValue = 100
    durationSlider.continuous = true

 // durationSlider.alpha = 0

    durationSlider.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    durationSlider.value = 0
    durationSlider.addTarget(self, action: "sliderValueDidChange:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    self.view.addSubview(durationSlider)

}

func sliderValueDidChange(sender:UISlider!) {
    print("value--\(sender.value)")
}
```

Everything works like charm until here, and I get the value change on the UISlider perfrectly.

---

However, as soon as I add `durationSlider.alpha = 0`, and use something like this in my `viewDidLoad()`:

```
 viewDidLoad() {
     ...
 let tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTapGestureRecognizer:")
 tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
 self.player.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}

 func handleTapGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 1.5, options: [], animations: {
        self.durationSlider.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 1.5, options: [], animations: {
        self.durationSlider.alpha = 0
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

At this point, I have 2 problems.

1) The UISlider is fading in instantly (without any duration or delay, as if I used `alpha = 1` directly - without using animateWithDuration), whereas it fades out nicely.

2) The UISlider doesn't trigger `sliderValueDidChange` if I use `alpha = 0` in viewDidLoad. However, if I try `alpha = 1`, `sliderValueDidChange` works as expected.

---

**Updated Code:**

This doesn't work.

```
func handleTapGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.4, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction], animations: {
        self.durationSlider.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: {completed in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 2.0, options: [], animations: {
            self.durationSlider.alpha = 0
        }, completion: nil)

    })   
}
```

However, this works:

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.4, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction], animations: {
        self.durationSlider.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: nil)
```

What I am trying to achieve is a video duration controller with that UISlider, so I want to show it when the user taps on the screen with making it available to interact, and if the user doesn't interact for x seconds, hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly controls are disabled when their alpha is < 0.5.

Your animation code is wrong. You have both animations with the same duration and same delay. They both run at the same time, which is wrong. You need to make it so the second one uses a delay that is the sum of the delay and the duration of the previous animation. (So if the first animation has a delay of 1 and a duration of 1.5, you want to give the second animation a delay of 1.0 + 1.5 = 2.5, so it starts right after the first animation is finished.

Alternately, you can put the second animation inside the completion block for the first with a delay of 0 so it starts as soon as the first animation completes.

Comment: I tried your approach. Now the animation visual seems nice, but . However, I still have my second problem. As I set alpha to 0 in viewDidLoad initially, I can't interract with the slider. I also tried initially setting alpha to 1 before `self.view.addSubview(durationSlider)` and after this set alpha to 1 (right after `self.view.addSubview(durationSlider)`). In both of the scenarios, the UISlider is not selectable/interractable.

Comment: By default user interaction is disabled during Try using the form of animateWithDuration that takes an options parameter and adding UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction.

Comment: Update: I have added [UIViewAnimationOption.AllowUserInteraction] in options, but it still doesn't let me interract the slider :/

Answer (score 1):

I think that is the intended behaviour. Alpha 0 means the user can't see it therefore not interact with it. I saw a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091013/uiview-alpha-0-causes-touches-to-be-dropped-to-the-view-below). Please also try to chain the animations.

```
 func handleTapGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 1.5, options: [], animations: {
        self.durationSlider.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion:  { completed in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 1.5, options: [], animations: {
            self.durationSlider.alpha = 0
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, but if you take a look in the `handleTapGestureRecognizer()`, I fade it in, and set the alpha to 1.0. I think you haven't read carefully my friend

Comment: Thanks for your edit. However, this time on `}, completion: {` bit, I am getting an error 'Cannot convert value of type '() -> Void' to expected argument type '((Bool) -> Void)?'

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to XCode now. Probably missing the completed parameter on the completion closure. Will update the answer.

Comment: I used your approach and used the duration and delays as yours. However, the UISlider is still unselectable where it works if I place the alpha to 1 in the viewDidLoad.

Comment: Have you tried to use 0 delay? Also, as we stated before, when the alpha is 0 the controller can't be interacted with. I guess it's working as designed.

Comment: But then I am setting the alpha to 1 but, it's still uninterractable. What do you think may be the problem? :S